# Namespace not found, though added .dll

Tags: .net, visual-studio, namespaces

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 web application. I added the a class library project, that have class as clsOperation, this class have 3 methods. I build this class. Add .dll to my web application as reference.Biult my website. but while I am trying to add a header in the code behind (using my namespace) the class's namespace is not appearing in intellisense. So I can't use it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You mention that it doesn't appear in Intellisense. Sometimes intellisense in Visual Studio can be a bit flakey. Have you tried adding the using statement manually?

Also, you class library will have a default namespace and so the using syntax needs this in it. e.g.

```
using MyClassLibraryName.myClassName;
```

Comment: Yeah, I've found intellisense in page directives don't work right for me in Visual Studio.  I just ignore it.

Comment: This is not matter of just intellisense ,it is matter of support. Means though i include the dll in my references, i can not get support of that namespace....so i can not access classes. Why this ?